# How to assemble a mips assembly file

Tags: cygwin, mips

I have a binary file in mips format.  I was able to disassemble it, make the changes I wanted to the assembly file in mips.  Now I would like to assemble it back into a bin file again.  I am using cygwin and am trying to do so with the ar utility.

**This is the original object dump:**

```
$ objdump -b binary -h test.bin

test.bin:     file format binary

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .data         00200004  00000000  00000000  00000000  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
```

I also have the assembly file (test.asm) which contains the mips instructions from the test.bin file.

**I then tried to assemble it by:**

```
ar -q test2.bin test.asm --target=elf32-big
```

and

```
ar -cr test2.bin test.asm --target=elf32-big
```

But in both cases I only get a bin file with the contents of the assembly file.  Can anyone help on what I am missing to assemble this back to a elf32-big binary?

Thanks Before Hand

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you'll need a MIPS assembler program.  If you have a full gcc MIPS cross-compiler, the name of the assembler should be something like `mips-as` or `as`.

Actually, it might be easier to compile it with `mips-gcc`, which will invoke the assembler and linker for you.

Comment: Will that compile from an ASM file?  I do not have the C source code. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is some way to get gcc to compile an ASM file.  You should start by renaming your file to `.s` and feeding it to GCC as input in the usual way.  There might be a lot of difficulties along the way though; be prepared to fix up the syntax of your assembly file, add missing directives, and things like that.